# Kubeflow vs other options

Tags: kubeflow

I am trying to find when it makes sense to create your own Kubeflow MLOps platform:

- If you are Tensorflow only shop, do you still need Kubeflow? Why not TFX only? Orchestration can be done with Airflow.
- Why use Kubeflow if all you are using scikit-learn as it does not support GPU, distributed training anyways? Orchestration can be done with Airflow.
- If you are convinced to use Kubeflow, cloud providers (Azure and GCP) are delivering ML pipeline concept (Google is using Kubeflow under the hood) as managed services. When it makes sense to deploy your own Kubeflow environment then? Even if you have a requirement to deploy on-prem, you have the option to use the cloud resources (nodes and data on cloud) to train your models, and only deploy the model to on-prem. Thus, using Azure or GCP AI Platform as managed service makes the most sense to deliver ML pipelines?

Comment: There are a lot of tools available in the market! I think it makes sense to use Ploomber since it enables the team moving fast and building modular pipelines. In addition it's super easy to get started. Check it out! https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Building an MLOps platform is an action companies take in order to accelerate and manage the workflow of their data scientists in production. This workflow is reflected in ML pipelines, and includes the 3 main tasks of `feature engineering`, `training` and `serving`.

Feature engineering and model training are tasks which require a pipeline orchestrator, as they have dependencies of subsequent tasks and that makes the whole pipeline prone to errors.

Software building pipelines are different from data pipelines, which are in turn different from ML pipelines.

A **software CI/CD flow** compiles the code to deploy-able artifacts and accelerates the software delivery process. So, *code in, artifact out*. It's being achieved by the invocation of compilation tasks, execution of tests and deployment of the artifact. Dominant orchestrators for such pipelines are Jenkins, Gitlab-CI, etc.

A **data processing flow** gets raw data and performs transformation to create features, aggregations, counts, etc. So *data in, data out*. This is achieved by the invokation of remote distributed tasks, which perform data transformations by storing intermediate artifacts in data repositories. Tools for such pipelines are Airflow, Luigi and some hadoop ecosystem solutions.

In the **machine learning flow**, the ML engineer writes code to train models, uses the data to evaluate them and then observes how they perform in production in order to improve them. So *code **and** data in, model out*. Hence the implementation of such a workflow requires a combination of the orchestration technologies we've discussed above.

**TFX** present this pipeline and proposes the use of components that perform these subsequent tasks. It defines a modern, complete ML pipeline, from building the features, to running the training, evaluating the results, deploying and serving the model in production

**Kubernetes** is the most advanced system for orchestrating containers, the defacto tool to run workloads in production, the cloud-agnostic solution to save you from a cloud vendor lock-in and hence optimize your costs.

**Kubeflow** is positioned as the way to do ML in Kubernetes, by implementing TFX. Eventually it handling the *code and data in, model out*. It provides a coding environment by implementing jupyter notebooks in the form of kubernetes resources, called `notebooks`. All cloud providers are onboard with the project and implement their data loading mechanisms across KF's components. The orchestration is implemented via **KF pipelines** and the serving of the model via **KF serving**. The metadata across its components are specified in the specs of the kubernetes resources throughout the platform.

In Kubeflow, the TFX components exist in the form of reusable tasks, implemented as containers. The management of the lifecycle of these components is achieved through Argo, the orchestrator of **KF pipelines**. Argo implements these workflows as kubernetes CRDs. In a `workflow` spec we define the dag tasks, the TFX components as containers, the metadata which will be written in the metadata store, etc. The execution of these workflows is happening nicely using standard kubernetes resources like pods, as well as *custom resource definitions* like `experiments`. That makes the implementation of the pipeline and the components language-agnostic, unline Airflow which implements the tasks in python only. These tasks and their lifecycle is then managed natively by kubernetes, without the need to use duct-tape solutions like Airflow's kubernetes-operator. Since everything is implemented as kubernetes resources, everything is a yaml and so the most Git friendly configuration you can find. Good luck trying to enforce version control in Airflow's dag directory.

The deployment and management of the model in production is done via **KF serving** using the CRD of `inferenceservice`. It utilizes *Istio*'s secure access to the models via its `virtualservices`, serverless resources using *Knative Serving*'s scale-from-zero `pods`, `revisions` for versioning, prometheus `metrics` for observability, `logs` in ELK for debugging and more. Running models in production could not be more SRE friendly than that.

On the topic of splitting training/serving between cloud and on-premise, the use of kubernetes is even more important, as it abstracts the custom infrastructure implementation of each provider, and so provides a unified environment to the developer/ml engineer.

Comment: a lot of useful info packed into one answer. thanks.